snmpset & snmpwalk for creating vlans
Is it possible to create, delete and update the vlan via snmpset and also make some ports part of it or delete some ports which are already in an existing vlan ?
using following I get the list of the vlans,
snmpwalk -c public -v2c 10.10.10.1 iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2

Regards
